# My code is inefficent, multiples of 3 and 5 from Project Euler but with a 10 second timeout conditon

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem Statement**

> This problem is a programming version of Problem 1 from
>   projecteuler.net
>
> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

**Input Format**

> First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is
>   followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

**Output Format**

> For each test case, print an integer that denotes the sum of all the
>   multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

**Constraints**

```
1≤T≤105 
1≤N≤109
```

**Sample Input**

```
2
10
100
```

**Sample Output**

```
23
2318
```

---

I'm doing the very first Project Euler question but with a time constraint for an extra challenge. If the process takes more than 10s it will autofail.

Here is a sample input:

```
2   # number of test cases
10  # first test case
100 # second test case
```

Here is my code:

```
test_case = int(input())
for x in range(0, test_case):       # Loops after every test case
    stop_value = int(input())

    answer = 0

    threes = 0
    while threes < stop_value:      # Checks 3s
        answer += threes
        threes += 3

    fives = 0
    while fives < stop_value:       # Checks 5s
        answer += fives
        fives += 5

    commons = 0
    while commons < stop_value:     # Check 15s
        answer -= commons
        commons += 15

    print(answer)
```

The problem will not show me the inputs when it is grading my solution but I am going to assume that one of the test cases is checking up until `10^9` which will take a lot more than 10 seconds to run.

---

**Previous attempt note:** Originally I had a simpler code which ran a for loop from `0` to `stop_value` which failed once the `stop_value` got too big so I attempted to make while loops (which I showed above) skipping in between everything.

---

**Next attempt:**

I tried to find the maximum multiple of each number and multiples that term by their own factorials but I get the wrong output.

To explain my thought process on why, I considered 10 as an example, 10//3 = 3. If I did 3!*3 it would be `[1*3,2*3,3*3]` = `[3,6,9]` which is all the multiples of 3 to the `stop_value` Edit: I noticed this is implemented incorrectly, I am currently considering for-loops for the factorials.

```
import math

test_case = int(input())
for x in range(0, test_case):       # Loops after every test case
    stop_value = int(input())

    threes = stop_value // 3
    fives = stop_value // 5
    commons = stop_value // 15

    answer = math.factorial(threes)*3 + math.factorial(fives)*5 - math.factorial(commons)*15

    print(answer)
```

**Your Output (stdout)**

```
13
26049952856435659498719093244723189200
```

**Expected Output**

```
23
2318
```

Comment: Please put the problem in the question, even if it is Euler, it's impolite to make us go to another site to help you.

Comment: Understood, sorry will do

Comment: There is a relationship between the sum of the natural numbers, and the sums of multiples of 3 or 5. You don't have to work out all of them. Also, you don't have to actually add up anything. Pair the first and last numbers, then the second and next to last, etc, and it becomes a multiplication.

Comment: Why are you using the factorial here? That's just wrong. And you don't need a loop to solve this.

Comment: @PeterWood thanks that's a great suggestion, working on that now

Comment: `sum({x for x in range(0,n,3)}.union({x for x in range(0,n,5)}))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a generalization of the sum of natural numbers. The general formula for a step size of `k` and a maximum number `n` (with `n` divisible by `k`) is: `n / k / 2 * (n + k)`.

```
def euler1 (n):
    max3 = range(0, n, 3)[-1]
    max5 = range(0, n, 5)[-1]
    max15 = range(0, n, 15)[-1]

    sum3 = (max3 + 3) * max3 // 3 // 2
    sum5 = (max5 + 5) * max5 // 5 // 2
    sum15 = (max15 + 15) * max15 // 15 // 2

    return sum3 + sum5 - sum15
```

```
>>> euler1(10)
23
>>> euler1(100)
2318
>>> euler1(10**100)
23333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333331666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666668
```

Comment: This solution is correct, but now when n is very large is is stating that this is wrong. I'm pretty sure this is due to rounding error when float is involved. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, you’re right. I have adjusted the answer by turning around the order of the multiplication and using integer division instead to keep it an int all the time (keeping the infinite precision).

Comment: The grader on Hacker Rank fails this and the code below as "too inefficient" for this problem.  I'm left scratching my head as I think their site might need some help.

Comment: @tijko They probably think that `range` is actually an enumerable object containing all those numbers, which you need to enumerate to reach the last item. When instead, it is a very efficient object that allows direct indexing at constant time.

Answer (score 2):

Although I completely agree that you should use the formula for the sum of natural numbers as `poke` stated, this can still be done generating all the numbers. For more information on solving your problem analytically, have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000) question from mathematics.SE

As for generating and summing all numbers, this was the fastest method I could quickly come up with:

```
n=10**9; sum(xrange(0,n,3)) + sum(xrange(0,n,5)) - sum(xrange(0,n,15))
```

This line takes about 5 seconds to execute on my i5, but it consumes a considerable amount of memory

Comment: I get a "fail" on time for both yours and his above.  Hacker Rank has a really odd grader.